# What is hidden file system in fdisk command in linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, command

When I wanted to choose the partition type in fdisk command, I see **Hidden File System** items (Character **l** inside the fdisk command). I was looking for a lot on the Internet, but I did not find a complete explanation of it. Someone can explain what this type of partition is and where it is used ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the list of recognized partition types that I get from FDISK that have "Hidden" in their names:

- `11  Hidden FAT12`
- `14  Hidden FAT16 <3`
- `16  Hidden FAT16`
- `17  Hidden HPFS/NTF`
- `1b  Hidden W95 FAT3`
- `1c  Hidden W95 FAT3`
- `1e  Hidden W95 FAT1`
- `27  Hidden NTFS Win`
- `84  OS/2 hidden or`

Those are (unofficially) documented in the page [List of partition identifiers for PCs](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html). From that list, it appears that they are used by OS/2 and Windows to hide partitions for various reasons:

- 11 (Hidden DOS 12-bit FAT)/14 (Hidden DOS 16-bit FAT <32M)/16 (Hidden DOS 16-bit FAT >=32M)/17 (Hidden IFS (e.g., HPFS):

  > When it boots a DOS partition, OS/2 Boot Manager will hide all primary
  >   DOS partitions except the one that is booted, by changing its ID: 01,
  >   04, 06 becomes 11, 14, 16. Also 07 becomes 17.
- 1b (Hidden WIN95 OSR2 FAT32)/1c (Hidden WIN95 OSR2 FAT32, LBA-mapped)/1e (Hidden WIN95 16-bit FAT, LBA-mapped): No details in the document, but likely OS/2-related as well
- 27 (Windows RE hidden partition):

  > On MBR disks, type 0x27. On GPT disks, GUID:
  >   DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC. A hidden version of a Windows RE
  >   type 0x7 partition with NTFS. When this is installed, reboot and press
  >   F8 in order to boot into this Recovery Environment.
- 84 (OS/2 hidden C: drive):

  > OS/2-renumbered type 04 partition.

These are largely obsolete partition types (with the exception of partition type 27), so you probably shouldn't ever come across them. Also, FDISK doesn't need to actually know what to do with these partitions: it only deals with the partition table (you can make a partition with whatever number you want and Linux generally won't care as long as there's a recognized file system in the partition.)